# Setting http get command as source in SpringXD

Tags: json, http-get, spring-xd

This command executed in SpringXD shell

```
http get --target https://webserviceaddress
```

gives me JSON document.

Is anybody has idea how to create stream with this as source ? 
I see way to make just custom module, but maybe I missed somehow simpler solution ...

Answer (score 1):

The `http` "command" is a convenience command in the XD shell, so that you don't have to use `curl` or any external command. It just makes a one-off http request to some endpoint (the default address being http://localhost:9000 which happens to be where the `http` *source module* would listen -- again, this is for convenience).

If you want to create a **stream**, then you need a module that is able to make http requests to a remote endpoint. The `http-client` processor module does just that. It needs to be triggered by some external source, *e.g.* the `trigger` module.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#http-client

Answer (score 1):

To use webservice with get method as source I need trigger as source and http-client as following module for example below stream will get content from webservice every 60 seconds and write it to file

```
stream create --name stream_name --definition "trigger --fixedDelay=60 | http-client --url='''https://webservice.url''' --httpMethod=GET | file" --deploy
```